# Does Grails has domain.find-by... option ":select" to limit column like rails?

Tags: grails, dns, findby

In rails,we can use Order.find(:all,:select=>"id,name...... or Order.where(....).select("id,name") to limit the column.

But i can not find the similar way in Grails. so can you give me some help for it? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any possible parameters for the Grails dynamic finders to limit the properties returned by the finder. The best alternative I know of is to use projections within a criteria, i.e.

```
Book.withCriteria {
    like 'author', 'Will%'
    projections {
        property 'title'
        property 'author'
    }
}
```

For more, see the [`criteria reference`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: +1, but a query with projections only returns a list of properties instead of domain instances, therefore you can not further update the properties with what returned from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't limit the columns returned when using a dynamic finder like `findBy`. Intead you must use either a [criteria query with projections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883056/2648), or a HQL query executed with [executeQuery](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html)